# How to find out if an EditText has been created?

Tags: android, object, android-edittext

In a dialog layout, I create a second EditText programmatically depending on user choices. When I want to return the inputs, I need to know if a second EditText has been created or not. And I don't understand how to make this check. My statement if (edittextTwo != null) is always null, even when the second EditText has been displayed and entered text into.

Here are the methods which create the second EditText and return their inputs:

if (edittextTwo != null)

```
private void displayASecondEdittext(String title) {
    ViewGroup layout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.layout_editdialog);
    TextView titleTwo = new TextView(this);
    titleTwo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)); 
    titleTwo.setText(title);
    layout.addView(titleTwo);

    EditText edittextTwo = new EditText(this);
    edittextTwo.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    layout.addView(edittextTwo);
}//END displayASecondInputfield


private void returnResult() {
    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, EditDialog.class);
    resultIntent.putExtra(EDITONE, edittextOne.getText().toString());
    if (edittextTwo != null) {
        resultIntent.putExtra(EDITTWO, edittextTwo.getText().toString());
        Log.v(TAG, "edittextTwo ="+edittextTwo.getText().toString());
    }
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, resultIntent);
    finish();
}//END returnResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

move `EditText edittextTwo;` out side of your method.  put it here:

```
public class myActivity extends Activity
    EditText edittextTwo = null;
```

And then, in your `DisplayASecondEditText()`, do this instead of what you have:

```
edittextTwo = new EditText(this);
```

This will make your declaration global, and allow all all methods to access the variable.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand how your code above even compiles, since `edittextTwo` is a local variable in `displayASecondEdittext`. Make it a member variable in your activity and it should work.